# Why won't image in subdirectory show but will if I move it up a level?

Tags: html, image, web, ftp, web-deployment

I am just learning web development and am having a problem I just can't seem to fix.

I have images I want to display on a page, in my ftp they are in book/detailed_image

On my page I have the img src

```
<img src="/new/site/images/book/detailed_image/book_one_detailed_View.jpg">
```

I have checked multiple times and the source is correct. If I move the image up a directory to the book directory and change the src the images display correctly.

What could be the cause of this?

The file attributes of the book and detailed_image directories are the same has are the attributes of the image files.

Using firebug it says the url failed to load.

Comment: Are you sure that even the path's case is correct? If you try to load the jpg into your browser directly (by typing the full URI in the location bar) does it show? What directory is your html file in? If you put a html file in the ..detailed_image directory, can you see it in the browser? Have you tried other browsers? And if you can see the file with ftp, can you put the ftp path in the img src, does it work then?

Comment: The case is correct. It doesn't show if I type the full URL it just displays my home page. If I add an html page that also just displays the home page content. Other browsers are the same. If i enter the FTP it asks for the password, when I enter it the image is not displaying on the page but if I highlight the line in firebug I can see the image is there instead of saying "failed to load url"

Comment: Hm, very odd. There must be something we're overlooking. Is your site live? Could I see it?

Comment: Sorry it's not a live site.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your html file in the same location as your `new` folder then there is no need to put a forward slash at the beginning of your url.

Change:

```
<img src="/new/site/images/book/detailed_image/book_one_detailed_View.jpg">
```

To:

```
<img src="new/site/images/book/detailed_image/book_one_detailed_View.jpg">
```

Comment: I've tried that but that's the cause. <img src="/new/site/images/book/detailed_image/book_one_detailed_View.jpg"> doesn't work <img src="/new/site/images/book/book_one_detailed_View.jpg"> does work. Just moving the image up a directory displays it correctly, the path is correct so it must be something with the detailed_image directory but I just don't know what :-(

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a problem with the permissions of the folder "detailed_image". If you do a chmod 755 detailed_image then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

this probably isn't the case for you, but I had the same problem - I got a 404 not found error with the image in images/Paris/p1.png but if I moved the image into the images folder it displayed correctly....I fixed my issue by changing the name of the 'Paris' folder to 'paris' - I have no idea why but it worked...

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue which I also had: it seems that the subdir "Images" has to have the same rights as the images contained therein.
I changed the access rights for the folder to "755" and added to include all subdirs  with the same rights, now it works!
Hope it does the same for you...